# algorithm used in depthimage_to_laserscan

Tags: ros, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i would like to know the algorithm used in 'depthimage_to_laserscan ' to convert 3D data to 2D data.is it RANSAC algorithm.someone please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227652/algorithm-used-in-depthimage_to_laserscan/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you might be missing what `depthimage_to_laserscan` does. In depth image, you have a depth value per pixel. This, together with the camera parameters, can be converted to X,Y,Z points. That package is simply transforming points at a given row of the depthimage to X,Y,Z by using the inverse Pin Hole model. There is not any algorithm.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-03-01**:
thank you...